# ¿Es correcto usar el futuro para hablar del presente/pasado?

Tags: gramática, futuro

Hay ciertas construcciones que me son muy familiares pero que al pensar detenidamente en ellas me entra la duda y no sé qué justificación gramatical tienen (o si simplemente son incorrectas). Tal es el caso de oraciones donde el verbo parece estar conjugado en futuro, pero claramente se entiende que se hace referencia a algo que ya pasó (o para describir cosas que pasan en general, pero no necesariamente en el futuro). Para explicarme mejor, unos ejemplos:

- ¿Qué habrá pasado? -> Aunque parece un futuro perfecto, con esto entiendo que algo pasó, y queremos saber qué es.
- ¿Qué será eso? -> Tiene casi el mismo sentido que "¿qué es eso?" pero contiene más duda, como sabiendo que una respuesta certera no es posible en el momento.
- ¿Qué querrá decir esa señora? -> Parecido al caso anterior. También se refiere a algo que se dijo o se está diciendo, pero no hay seguridad en obtener una respuesta directa, como sería el caso de preguntar "¿Qué quiere decir esa señora?"

¿Son estos usos regionales (Colombia o latinoamérica) o se usan en toda parte? Si son correctos, ¿cómo le explicaría a un extranjero esa gramática?

Comment: Aquí en Europa también usamos esas formas

Comment: Regionales no son, ya te digo que en España se usan de la misma forma. Si no recuerdo mal, creo que se trata del futuro de probabilidad.

Comment: Pienso que es más una especie de condicional futuro (a falta de un mejor nombre) que usamos para denotar el pasado. Solo una observación, tienes razón sobre que es un poco extraño de utilizarlo de esta manera. En todo caso en muchas otras partes del mundo se usa, incluso en iberia entonces es mas o menos universal.

Comment: Es más: el futuro simple se está perdiendo poco a poco con valor, pues, futuro (hay países que apenas lo usa), pero sigue en vigor en todos los países con el valor epistémico. ( el condicional, por cierto, tiene el mismo valor epistémico en el pasado: ¿Qué hora sería cuando llegaste? --> ¿Qué hora imaginas que era/podía ser cuando llegaste?)

Comment: En cuanto a cómo explicarlo a un extranjero, si habla inglés es muy sencillo: basta con explicarle que funciona como el modal "will". En presente: Golpean la puerta. ¿Será Juan? (Will that be John?). En pasado funciona parecido a "must have". En este sitio: http://essay-editor.net/blog/how-to-master-future-perfect-tense encontré este ejemplo: Your admirers will have noticed your positive attitude to charity. (En español es exactamente igual: Tus admiradores habrán notado...)

Comment: @guifa Entiendo que te refieres al futuro compuesto, ¿no?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tal como ya apuntaba Charlie en los comentarios, se trata del **futuro de probabilidad**:

> **23.14h** Se llama FUTURO DE CONJETURA, FUTURO DE PROBABILIDAD o FUTURO EPISTÉMICO el que introduce alguna suposición del hablante relativa al presente, como en *Serán las ocho* en el sentido de 'Probablemente son las ocho' o 'Deben de ser las ocho'; *Estará enfadado conmigo*, en el de 'Supongo que está enfadado conmigo' (...)
>
> **23.14i** El futuro de conjetura también admite paráfrasis con verbos modales:
>
> > *¿Qué costará? ~ ¿Qué puede costar?;*
> >     *Estará ocupado ~ Debe de estar ocupado.*
>
> así como otros que introducen suposiciones y otras actitures proposicionales similares (...)

Fuente: [*Nueva Gramática*](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=bMfDRKyvXaPgAcLW), RAE.

Es un uso habitual tanto en LATAM como en España.

Sobre cómo explicárselo a un extranjero...
Aunque la RAE se extiende mucho más en el análisis de las interpretaciones y escenarios de uso, creo que la más fácil de comprender es que lo usamos cuando estamos bastante seguros de la respuesta a la pregunta que se plantea. Tan seguros, de hecho, que usamos un tiempo futuro, que implica certeza, antes que uno condicional.

Comment: Buena respuesta, sobretodo tu comentario final. Saludos.

Comment: La explicación del último párrafo puede servir para las frases afirmativas como «estará ocupado» o «serán las ocho» pero ¿cómo se explican las interrogativas como las de los ejemplos de @MauricioMartinez? Ahí ya no estamos seguros de nada.

Comment: No lo había pensado de esa forma, en tal caso no es solo que estemos bastante seguros sino totalmente seguros

Answer (score 5):

Extraído de la *Nueva Gramática*, [párrafo 23.14h](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=SefIJfgRojgEYFFm):

> Se llama FUTURO DE CONJETURA, FUTURO DE PROBABILIDAD o FUTURO EPISTÉMICO el que introduce alguna suposición del hablante relativa al presente, como en *Serán las ocho* en el sentido de 'Probablemente son las ocho' o 'Deben de ser las ocho' [...].

En los siguientes párrafos se profundiza bastante en este uso del futuro, dando numerosos ejemplos similares a los que propones, en los cuales se sustituye una probabilidad presente por un futuro, como en *Estará ocupado*, equivalente a *Debe de estar ocupado*.

En el [párrafo 23.16r](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=OeUobNvihJAzZUgv) se añade:

> La interpretación de futuro de conjetura [...] se extiende al futuro compuesto, como en *Habrá estado enfermo ~ Probablemente ha estado enfermo* [...].

Así pues, este uso del futuro es universal y está perfectamente estudiado en la gramática. Aunque, curiosamente, sí que parece haber una diferencia regional:

> El futuro compuesto de conjetura equivale en unos países a un pretérito perfecto compuesto [...], como en *Me habré equivocado ~ Probablemente me he equivocado*, y en otros, a un pretérito perfecto simple [...], como en *Me habré equivocado ~ Probablemente me equivoqué*.

Sobre cómo explicárselo a un extranjero, una opción sería explicar que frases como *¿Qué hora será?* usan el futuro porque implican que ahora mismo no lo sabes, pero en un futuro lo puedes averiguar.

Answer (score 4):

*Con esta respuesta parcial, voy a dirigirme a la última parte de la pregunta, ¿cómo le explicaría a un extranjero esa gramática?  Voy a tomar el caso de explicar a alguien que habla inglés.*

Although there is a future tense in Spanish, it isn't often used to talk about simple future facts.  (For that, the present tense plus an appropriate adverb or context usually gets the job done.)

But there's an idiomatic way to use the future tense, to express speculation, for example:

- ¿Qué habrá pasado? | *I wonder what happened. (Literally, what will have happened?*
- ¿Qué será eso? | *What is that? (Literally, what will that be?)*
- ¿Qué querrá decir esa señora? | *What does that woman mean? (Literally, what will that woman mean?)*

You can think of it like a prediction of what the conclusion may turn out to be.

To get your feet wet and start using this construction, try using it when proposing a possible explanation, by prefacing your sentence with "¿Será que ...?

For example:

> ¿Será que tal funcionario del gobierno está mintiendo? | *Do you think such-and-so government official will turn out to have been lying?*
>
> ¿Será que se durmió desde los primeros acordes del concierto? | *Is it likely that he fell asleep right from the opening chords of the concerto?*

As you gain experience, you'll be able to be more colorful, with a specific verb conjugated in the future tense, for example:

> ¿Tal funcionario del gobierno estará mintiendo?
>
> ¿Se habrá dormido desde los primeros acordes del concierto?

Answer (score 3):

Ciertos diálogos que utilizan verbos conjugados en futuro de indicativo no se utilizan para hablar de acciones futuras sino para expresar hipótesis referidas al momento presente. El hablante aún no tiene toda la información necesaria para expresar una afirmación, no sabe qué pasa exactamente y expresa lo que él cree probable o aproximado, por ejemplo:

> - ¿Será que está enfermo?
> - ¿Qué estará pasando allá?

También se usa para suposiciones o hipótesis en respuesta a preguntas:

> - ¿Por qué no vino tu amigo?
>
>   -No lo sé, ¿estará enfermo en su casa?
> - ¿Por qué ella está tan nerviosa?
>
>   -¿Será que querrá decirme algo importante?

Comment: Hola @Omega Kewt, bienvenido a [Spanish Language](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/). Muchas gracias por tu aportación, en mi opinión está bien pero podrías incluso mejorarla citando alguna fuente (la [RAE](http://www.rae.es) principalmente) o hablando de tu experiencia como nativo o hispanoparlante del nivel que sea. ¡Gracias!

Comment: @Alicia Gracias, es mi primer post, lo tendre en cuenta para futuros aportes.