# The use of futuro perfecto other than "I will have finished"

Tags: gramática, verbos, futuro

I watched a movie yesterday (translated from English to Spanish), in which one man asked another the following with the following translation to Spanish:

English original: "*It has been an enormously profitable, as I imagine you noticed*" = Spanish: "*Esto ha producido cuantiosos beneficios, como imagino que habrá observado.*" [it was in both speech and subtitles and subtitles have different text in other places from Spanish speech, so this shouldn't be a mistake of translation]

Why in this scene futuro perfecto was used?

Also, in general what is the usage of futuro perfecto besides similar usage of similar tense in English (ex.: "*I will have it finished by tomorrow 2 o'clock*")? Even here for this "2 o'clock" example in English, more simple future tense in Spanish can be used instead, I guess (either futuro simple or present simple or voy a + inf). I rarely if ever encountered use of this tense (futuro perfecto) in Spanish.

By the way, in same scene the guy said: "*Como seguramente sabrá*" and in original in English it was "*As you probably know*". But here I know that futuro (simple) is sometimes used for wondering in Spanish. If I am wrong, please correct me.

Comment: Note that the direct translation "as I imagine you will have noticed" is idiomatic in English as well.

Comment: This question has already been asked [here](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23946/12637), but in a more general way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know about the use of the future for wondering, then you have half-answered yourself. Note that the use of the future tense for wondering respects the tense in which the original sentence is written, so the transformations are as follows:

> Como seguramente sabe ⇒ *como seguramente sabrá*
>   Como seguramente ha observado ⇒ *como seguramente habrá observado*

As *sabe* is in the present tense, you use the simple future. But *ha observado* is an action that has just happened and is in the past, so the "wondering future" applies to the *haber* verb, hence *habrá observado*.

Other similar examples:

> *No quiero ni imaginar cuánto dinero te habrás gastado.*
>   *La de aventuras que habrá vivido ese marinero.*
>   *—Hacía tiempo que Fulano no venía por la oficina, ¿no? —Habrá estado enfermo.*
>   *¿Habrase visto semejante desfachatez?*

You can read more about the *futuro de conjetura* applied to this tense in [paragraph 23.16r](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=wuhNbzBihJdzCUgt) of the Spanish *Gramática*, where you can also find an example in the first person singular:

> *Pedí una semana de vacaciones y aquí estoy. Algo habré venido a buscar.*

Comment: Not only simple and compound future but even conditional can be used, e.g. when you're reporting a "future in the past" (*Charlie me contó que había pedido una semana de vacaciones y ahí estaba. Algo **habría venido** a buscar.*)