# Quizás + Futuro perfecto is correct?

Tags: tiempos-verbales, futuro

Is it correct to say "quizás habran ido" for express supposition in the past, or the "quizás" is unnecessary?
I mean if i wanted to use presente perfecto it would have been "quizás han ido" but here im not sure what to do.

Another question is, what is the name of this words like "quizás, tal vez...." which express probability and where can i find the gramatic rules related ro them?

Thanks

Comment: [grammar rules, not gramtic]. Please capitalize the I pronoun. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Quizás" and "tal vez" are adverbs that indicate probability.

Since the future perfect already expresses past probability, it would be redundant to use it with those adverbs. It just wouldn't sound right.

You can say:

1. Habrán ido al cine.
2. Quizás / Tal vez han ido al cine.
3. Quizás / Tal vez hayan ido al cine.

The difference between (3) and (2) is that (3) expresses a weaker probability than (2).

You may find [this related thread](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/42967/habr%C3%A1-sido-to-express-hypothesis-in-the-past/42968#42968) useful.

Comment: How do you translate: Maybe they will have gone by the time we return. Isn't that future perfect in Spanish?

Comment: I would translate it as: Es probable que se hayan ido para cuando regresemos/estemos de vuelta.