# Uso de condicional vs futuro perfecto para adivinar lo que sucedió en el pasado

Tags: gramática, condicional

En un artículo en inglés https://www.realfastspanish.com/grammar/the-spanish-conditional-tense-5-uses leí lo siguiente (en el punto 4):

"You can use the Spanish conditional tense to guess or form a hypothesis about what could have happened in the past but only in the simple and imperfect past tenses. If you want to form a hypothesis in the present perfect tense you have to use the future perfect tense.

-Pregunta: *¿Sabes qué hizo Paco ayer?*
-Hipótesis: *No sé, **iría** a la playa.*

-Pregunta: *¿Sabes qué país visitaron tus padres en su viaje?*
-Hipótesis: *No me acuerdo, **visitarían** Francia.*

-Pregunta: ¿*Sabes por qué María estuvo de mal humor la semana pasada*?
-Hipótesis: *No estoy seguro, supongo que **estaría** muy ocupada.*"

Preguntas:

1. Lo que explicó el autor, ¿es correcto?
2. En esta cadena [¿Es correcto usar el futuro para hablar del presente/pasado?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/23946/es-correcto-usar-el-futuro-para-hablar-del-presente-pasado) futuro perfecto fue usado para adivinar lo que sucedió en pasado (teniendo en cuenta los diferencias regionales). Por qué no usar lo mismo en los ejemplos del autor? De esta cadena (user Charlie):

"*Aunque, curiosamente, sí que parece haber una diferencia regional:
El futuro compuesto de conjetura equivale en unos países a un pretérito perfecto compuesto [...], como en Me habré equivocado ~ Probablemente me he equivocado, y en otros, a un pretérito perfecto simple [...], como en Me habré equivocado ~ Probablemente me equivoqué.*"

P.S. Por adelantado les agradezco a todos ustedes los que corrijan errores en mi letra si haya algunos, o en gramática o en uso de palabras o en algo más.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De estos tres grupos de oraciones:

> -Pregunta: ¿Sabes qué hizo Paco ayer? -Hipótesis: No sé, iría a la playa.
>
> -Pregunta: ¿Sabes qué país visitaron tus padres en su viaje? -Hipótesis: No me acuerdo, visitarían Francia.
>
> -Pregunta: ¿Sabes por qué María estuvo de mal humor la semana pasada? -Hipótesis: No estoy seguro, supongo que estaría muy ocupada."

solo el tercero es correcto (mi consejo sincero es que dejes de estudiar con *realfastspanish*)

Para usar solo verbos, sin adverbios, en los dos primeros funcionaría el futuro perfecto:

> -Pregunta: ¿Sabes qué hizo Paco ayer? -Hipótesis: No sé, **habrá ido** a la playa.
>
> -Pregunta: ¿Sabes qué país visitaron tus padres en su viaje? -Hipótesis: No me acuerdo, **habrán visitado** Francia.

La oración en el tercer diálogo funciona porque, a diferencia de las otras dos que hacen una conjetura sobre algo que la persona **hizo** (tal vez fue a la playa -> habrá ido a la playa / tal vez visitaron Francia -> habrán visitado Francia), la tercera hace referencia a lo que probablemente la persona **hacía** en ese momento (tal vez estaba muy ocupada -> estaría muy ocupada).

Para completar la respuesta, copio lo que encontré en [esta página](http://hispanoteca.eu/Gram%C3%A1ticas/Gram%C3%A1tica%20espa%C3%B1ola/Condicional%20simple%20-%20valores%20y%20usos.htm), que transcribe en gran parte lo que dice la Nueva Gramática de la Lengua Española sobre el condicional de conjetura (las negritas son mías):

> CONDICIONAL DE CONJETURA
>
> «El condicional de conjetura (también llamado de probabilidad y epistémico) se diferencia del futuro del mismo tipo en que se refiere al pasado en lugar de al presente. **Admite paráfrasis similares con el verbo en pretérito imperfecto**. Así, ***Serían** las diez* equivale a ‘**Probablemente eran** las diez’, y ***Tendría** entonces treinta años* a ‘**Podía tener** entonces treinta años’.
>
> [...]
>
> También se usa en combinación con un adverbio de probabilidad, como en *Seguramente estaría cansado*, subordinado a un verbo de suposición: *Me imaginé que tendría las manos con un cigarrillo del que no se tragaría el humo*, así como en las oraciones exclamativas de sentido consecutivo encabezadas por *si* y pronunciadas con entonación suspendida: *Si estaría cansado que se durmió haciendo el examen.*
>
> El condicional de conjetura, pero no el futuro, admite paráfrasis con el verbo *poder* en su interpretación epistémica o impersonal: *No recuerdo cuánto me {costaría ~ pudo costar}*; *Pero ¡quién me mandaría [‘pudo mandar’] a mí salir de casa!* (Mendizábal, Cumpleaños). Este uso de *cantaría* está próximo al futuro compuesto de conjetura, así como al condicional compuesto: *¡Quién me {**mandaría ~ habrá mandado ~ habría mandado ~ pudo mandar**} salir de casa!*
>
> No existe, en cambio, la perífrasis «iría a + infinitivo», ya que a la alternancia *Cuando llegó, {**serían ~ eran**} aproximadamente las cuatro de la tarde* no corresponde propiamente la variante iban a ser. Cabe entender esta asimetría como la consecuencia natural de que «ir a + infinitivo» se considere un futuro analítico.» [RAE: NGLE-Manual, 23.8.1d-e]
>
> El contenido aproximativo se produce cuando en el contexto tratamos de establecer una cantidad que no sabemos precisar: ***Habría** cincuenta personas en la sala.* **Es parafraseable mediante el imperfecto de indicativo** y la cantidad acompañada de una palabra o locución que indique aproximación, como aproximadamente, unos, unas, hacia, sobre, cerca de, poco más o menos u otras expresiones equivalentes: *Había unas cincuenta personas en la sala*.

Como podemos observar, el condicional simple **en general** se equipara al pretérito **imperfecto** (no al perfecto simple) del indicativo acompañado por algún adverbio indicativo de probabilidad. No obstante, se mencionan dos ejemplos donde funciona el condicional de conjetura como equivalente al pretérito perfecto, que son totalmente ajenos al el español rioplatense pero que, de acuerdo con DGaleano y según confirma la NGLE, funcionarían bien en otros dialectos:

*No recuerdo cuánto me {costaría ~ pudo costar}*.
*Pero ¡quién me mandaría [‘pudo mandar’] a mí salir de casa!*.

Comment: Entendido. Quisiera precisar - ¿por qué en el tercero funcionaría condicional? Hay alguna regla de que con adverbios se puede usar condicional para adivinar sobre lo que sucedió en el pasado?

Comment: Buen punto. Lo agregué a la respuesta.

Comment: @Alex “mi consejo sincero es que dejes de estudiar con realfastspanish” - estoy de acuerdo con Gustavson

Comment: @Traveller En realidad, ahora no estudio con realfastspanish. Ya empecé tener dudas de este sitio web antes. Pero quería analizar este artículo sobre el uso de condicional antes de usar los consejos de este artículo y por fin lo hice. Me alegro de que haya hecho esto.

Comment: Nuevamente otra pregunta sobre *realfastspanish* O eso es escrito por un Colombiano o no se que pasa, pero para mi las 3 frases al principio de esta respuesta son correctas y de uso muy frecuente en Colombia. @Alex si vas a viajar a Argentina deja de estudiar en ese sitio pero si vas a viajar a Colombia ese es el lugar :)

Comment: @DGaleano muy interesante.. Es bueno saber sobre las diferencias en dialectos debido a que intento no limitarme a algún país al estudiar español